# Backup and restore of Hsqldb database in java code

Tags: java, sql, backup, hsqldb

I am new in Hsqldb database. I want to know how to take backup and restore of Hsqldb database through java code.

Comment: Can't you simply copy the db file?

Comment: Please [refer](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_backup)

Answer (score 4):

Use the `BACKUP DATABASE TO` command.

Here is a link to the documentation:

[HSQLDB System Management Documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_online_backup)

I haven't tested this, but I imagine it's something along the lines of:

```
String backup = "BACKUP DATABASE TO " + "'" + filePath + "' BLOCKING";

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(backup);  

preparedStatement.execute();
```

You'll want to wrap it in a try-catch block of course.

As far as restoring the db goes, I think you have to perform that while the database is offline using the DbBackupMain application.  So you would issue this command at the command line:

```
java -cp hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.lib.tar.DbBackupMain --extract tardir/backup.tar dbdir
```

Comment: using `DbBackupMain`, Can I able to specify the local path name in **tardir** placeholder ? I want it to a specific location. I extracted the **HSQL** DB in D:\Database\hsqldb\ path and my database is in D:\Database\HSQLDatabase\ path. How can I specify this to create a back up ? in D:\Database\Backup\ this path ? Please help

Comment: using the `PreparedStatement` execution back-up is creating. But it is creating the multiple copies in the specified location path. how do I modify to update/overright to the existed one ? So that I can manage one copies of the back-up file

Answer (score 3):

Each **HyperSQL database** is called a **catalog**. There are three types of catalog depending on how the data is stored.

*Types of catalog data* :

**mem**: stored entirely in RAM - without any persistence beyond the JVM process's life

**file**: stored in filesystem files

**res**: stored in a Java resource, such as a Jar and always read-only

To back up a *running catalog*, obtain a JDBC connection and issue a BACKUP DATABASE command in SQL. In its most simple form, the command format below will backup the database as a single .tar.gz file to the given directory.

```
BACKUP DATABASE TO <directory name> BLOCKING [ AS FILES ]
```

The directory name must end with a slash to distinguish it as a directory, and the whole string must be in single quotes like so: 'subdir/nesteddir/'.

To back up an *offline catalog*, the catalog must be in shut down state. You will run a Java command like

```
 java -cp hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.lib.tar.DbBackupMain --save tardir/backup.tar dbdir/dbname
```

. In this example, the database is named dbname and is in the dbdir directory. The backup is saved to a file named backup.tar in the tardir directory.

where tardir/backup.tar is a file path to the *.tar or *.tar.gz file to be created in your file system, and dbdir/dbname is the file path to the catalog file base name.

You use DbBackup on your operating system command line to **restore** a catalog from a backup.

```
java -cp hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.lib.tar.DbBackupMain --extract tardir/backup.tar dbdir
```

where tardir/backup.tar is a file path to the *.tar or *.tar.gz file to be read, and dbdir is the target directory to extract the catalog files into. Note that dbdir specifies a directory path, without the catalog file base name. The files will be created with the names stored in the tar file.
For more details [refer](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_backup)

Answer (score 0):

So in java + SPring + JdbcTemplate

**Backup (On-line):**

```
@Autowired
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public void mainBackupAndRestore() throws IOException {
  ...
    jdbcTemplate.execute("BACKUP DATABASE TO '" + sourceFile.getAbsolutePath() + "' BLOCKING");
}
```

This will save .properties, .scripts and .lobs file to a tar in sourceFile.getAbsolutePath().

**Restore:**

```
DbBackupMain.main(new String[] { "--extract", baseDir.getAbsolutePath(),
                    System.getProperty("user.home") + "/restoreFolder" });
```

This will get files from baseDir.getAbsolutePath() and will put them in userHome/restoreFolder where you can check if all restore is OK.
lobs contains lob/blob data, scripts contains executed queries.

[image]